# Stretching frame layout's layer to another layer

Tags: android, android-layout

There is a frame layout on my screen (see code below). This layout consists of  2 layers. The first layer is LinearLayout with several views and its height = `"wrap_content"`. The second is ProgressBar with `"fill_parent"`. I need the progressbar to stretch itself to the linear layout's height, but now it doesn't consider linear layout's height.

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_drawable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/file_item_background">

    ---
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `FrameLayout`, try a `RelativeLayout`.

You can then set `android:layout_alignTop` and `android:layout_alignBottom` on your ProgressBar to match the LinearLayout's height like so:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_drawable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/my_linear_layout"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/my_linear_layout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_linear_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/file_item_background">

    ---
</LinearLayout>
```

Another option would be to manually adjust the height in code.

In general, you want to use a RelativeLayout if your layout requirements call for a position or a size relative to another view.